# Use secondary domain as alternative url for missing urls on primary domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need all image, css.. that are not on my primary domain to be requested on a secondary domain.
For example, if the page calls https://primary.domain/subfolder/css/style.css?1678369663 and that style.css doesn't exist in the path, I want the request to be done to https://secondary.domain/css/style.css?1678369663

So I added that to my primary domain htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ https://secondary.domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I still get 404 and don't see any 301.

The whole htaccess:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre « BEGIN WordPress » et « END WordPress » sont générées
# dynamiquement, et doivent être modifiées uniquement via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives situées entre ces marqueurs sera surchargée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#my redir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ https://secondary.domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is this all your .htaccess contains in terms of rewriting? If not, show us the rest, so that we can see what you are doing with those two lines in context.

Comment: This is a wordpress website so there's the wordpress redirections, I added the full htaccess as an edit

Comment: Looks like you made the typical mistake of getting the order wrong. WordPress already rewrites every request that does not match a physically existing folder or file, to its own index.php, in the block before where you inserted yours. So you need to place your rewrite _before_ WP's own.

Comment: I though as the wordpress redirect still point to a non existing file, my redirection will be used next, that seems the right behaviour to me...

Comment: That nearly works, but the page domain/subfolder redirect to secondarydomain/, even if I use .+ instead of .* I don't understand

Comment: _"I though as the wordpress redirect still point to a non existing file"_ - it _doesn't_. The conditions in that block have determine that the requested URL does not match any folder or file, and therefor the request has been rewritten to the index.php at this point. And the `L` flag prevents evaluation of any further rules in this round of processing.

Comment: _"but the page domain/subfolder redirect to secondarydomain/, even if I use .+ instead of .*"_ - due to `R=301`, your browser is very likely to have cached that redirect now. Clear your cache, or test in a private window/tab. (Using 302 instead while still testing, and only replacing it with 301 when everything works as desired, is a good idea in such cases.)